# Stars significance level in r

Tags: r, statistics, significant-digits, significance

Hi This ist the definiftion of the significance test in r. If you do a linear regression in r this is what r retuns.
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘***’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
My question is for *** what is the significance level?It cannot be 0.
** means siginificance level of 0.1% and * is significance level of 1% and . is at level 5%.Is that right?

Comment: *between* 0 and 0.001. You can see the code for the significant stars in the last example of `?symnum`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the code in `printCoefmat`:

```
if (signif.stars) {
                Signif <- symnum(pv, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
                  cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
                  symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
                Cf <- cbind(Cf, format(Signif))
```

You can think of `symnum` as a specialized form of `findInterval` where the values are the location of the interval defined by n+1 cutpoints for n interval-names.